# How to match variables in formula with regular epxressions

Tags: regex

If I have a formula similar to this: **a + b - c * (exp(a*b) ) / 3**

I want to match only variables(a, b, c). For me, **[a-zA-Z]+** does the job. However I do not want to match **exp** function. How can I achieve this with regular expressions? I use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\b(?!\s*\()
```

more common notion of acceptable variable names would be

```
\b([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\b(?!\s*\()
```

with dots in function names it becomes

```
(?:[^.]|^)\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b(?!(\.|\s*\())
```

(the variable will be in the first capturing match)

Comment: Great! What if my "exp" function has a dot like "Math.exp()" ?

Comment: @lukas.pukenis - there it is.

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to **\b[A-z]\b** will match single a-z letters not standing next to other characters.

Comment: You can’t write `[A-z]`!!!! That matches code points that are higher than Z and lower than a. See the big problem?

Comment: Would you care to give an example of what is wrong with it? :s

Comment: What’s wrong with it is that “Z” is code point 90 but “a” is code point 97.  That means `[A-z]` also erroneously matches the six code points 91–96.  ***BAD IDEA!***

Comment: Using regexbuddy i'm only able to match the '_' character that's included in the \w too. I'll admit it's not accurate but not sure it's what you're blowing it up to be.

Comment: I’m not “blowing it up to be”. `[A-z]` also includes code points 91  [    92  \    93  ]    94  ^    95  _
      96  ` — which is *nuts*.